# Nginx redirecting before HSTS certificate error

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

So the issue I'm having seems to be that with a cert from cacert.org and HSTS set if you visit www.domain.com you get an error, while if you visit domain.com (no-www) the certificate is fine.

What I'd like to do is redirect from www to no-www (you can't have wildcard certs from cacert) but it seems this is being interrupted because the browser's been to the website with HSTS enabled before, loads the www.domain.com website and throws a lovely great error onto the page. And of course because HSTS is in use there's no way to even bypass the certificate error! It just informs you the issue should be temporary. Respectively in Firefox and Chromium:

> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.

And

> You cannot visit www.domain.com right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.

I'm open to any suggestions! I thought redirecting from www to no-www would be the best answer, but if you can suggest something else I'm listening (second certificate for www perhaps? But that seems a little overdoing it).

Comment: Don't they include `www` prefix?

Comment: Check with your certificate provider if the cert can be reissued with www.domain.com as an alternate name. Something similar to paypal.com (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=paypal.com) -- 

Common names paypal.com;
Alternative names paypal.com www.paypal.com;
Prefix handling Both (with and without WWW).

See https://serverfault.com/questions/447222/ssl-certificates-for-domain-without-www for your issue reversed (no-www not working, www working).

Comment: I will ask them - but for example when using a Common Name of "www.domain.com" they attempt to send an email to "root@www.domain.com" which kinda looks like it won't work (I don't really want emails handled on the www subdomain.)